# How to reinstall magento 2 extension properly?

Tags: magento2, database, extensions, installation

When using M1 i could reinstall the extension (launch  setup/upgrade) just deleting the extension recording from the `core_resource` table. During the second magento address (or after cache refreshing) the extension executed all the files properly beginning from the 0 version.

Unfortunately i could not find the detailed information on how to reinstall the extension previously installed on my magento 2. Maybe somebody faced the same issue and knows the plan of actions for reinstalling the extension on magento 2 and could help. Your help will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

Example:

1. I've got module v. 2.0.0 successfully installed with own tables
2. I've delete the tables manually from the database
3. I've got module v. 2.0.0 without tabels

How to reinstall tables without completely uninstalling and installing module?

**UPDATE:**

```
bin/magento module:uninstall <VendorName>_<ModuleName>
<VendorName>_<ModuleName> is not an installed composer package
```

<sub>where the `<VendorName>_<ModuleName>` - is the real vendor name and module name of the my module.</sub>

```
bin/magento module:status
List of enabled modules:
Magento_Store
.....
<VendorName>_<ModuleName>
.....
Magento_Weee
Magento_CatalogWidget
Magento_Wishlist
List of disabled modules:
None
```

**UPDATE 2**

My extension has the same name attribute value as in `<VendorName>` and `<ModuleName>`, in  `app/code/<VendorName>/<ModuleName>/etc/module.xml` as it is indicated further:

```
<module name="<VendorName>_<ModuleName>" setup_version="1.0.0" />
```

In addition:

```
vagrant@magento-dev:/var/www/mgn2$ bin/magento module:disable <VendorName>_<ModuleName>
The following modules have been disabled:
- <VendorName>_<ModuleName>

Cache cleared successfully.
Generated classes cleared successfully. Please re-run Magento compile command
Info: Some modules might require static view files to be cleared. Use the optional --clear-static-content option to clear them.
vagrant@magento-dev:/var/www/mgn2$ bin/magento module:enable <VendorName>_<ModuleName>
The following modules have been enabled:
- <VendorName>_<ModuleName>

To make sure that the enabled modules are properly registered, run 'setup:upgrade'.
Cache cleared successfully.
Generated classes cleared successfully. Please re-run Magento compile command
Info: Some modules might require static view files to be cleared. Use the optional --clear-static-content option to clear them.
```

This `bin/magento setup:upgrade` goes without any errors.

**UPDATE 2:**
I’ve found the additional information. Maybe it will be useful for somebody.

[mazhalai](https://github.com/mazhalai) writes:

> module:uninstall is intended to be used, only if you are absolutely
> certain, that the module wont be used any longer. However, other
> modules may have dependencies on the module that is to be removed.
> Hence we use composer remove, which calculates dependencies and
> removes code of the module from the file system. **We cannot uninstall a
> module that is NOT installed via composer**, since there is no way for
> us to know about dependencies in such a situation. It is risky to
> remove data and code in such a case. Hence, it is recommended that for
> modules NOT installed via composer, manual clean up of the database
> and filesystem is necessary. In module enable/disable, the code is
> never removed from the filesystem, so that it can be used if required
> at a later time. Hence, it is not removed from the setup_module table.

[Link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2098)

PS: I am using the Magento 2.0.4

Comment: What is in name field of `module.xml` of the module? That should be `<VendorName>_<ModuleName>. Also, how did you install this module initially?

Comment: @Maddy I’ve updated my question. I’ve written the module from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but if you added module manually in `app/code` as opposed to `composer require` you cannot uninstall it. That's why the command says `<VendorName>_<ModuleName> is not an installed composer package` Also, uninstall will only work if the module has uninstall script which implements https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Setup/UninstallInterface.php

Comment: ETA: Also, uninstall will only work *in the way that you intended(i.e remove tables and data)* if the module has uninstall script which implements https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Setup/UninstallInterface.php

Comment: @Maddy Thank you for your answer, but how can i reinstall the module (tables) in my case?

Comment: run `bin/magento module:enable` and then `bin/magento setup:upgrade`, also make sure module is removed from `setup_module` table before doing so.

Comment: @Maddy Still have no luck. Module is enabled, bin/magento setup:upgrade goes without any errors, but still could not see the new tables from the InstallSchema.php :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38020/discussion-between-maddy-and-siarhey-uchukhlebau).

Comment: Could you update your question to include the ALL IMPORTANT part that Maddy mentioned, "make sure module is removed from setup_module table before doing so", since it appears to be the key to forcing it to reinstall its schema.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To run your extension again you need to remove your extension entry from **setup_module** table also remove your table which are created by your extension script then run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Thanks

Comment: Worked like a charm!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can run

> php bin/magento module:uninstall module_name

Above code will uninstall your extension. Then run bellow code

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

From your root folder. This will do the update for all extensions

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I’ve tried this way but it doesn’t reinstall the tables from setup extension files (Setup/InstallSchema.php).

Comment: Did you change the version???

Comment: I am not going to update the extension, i want to reinstall it i.e. install the current version recurrently

Comment: Then first uninstall it and then again install it

Comment: i update my answer check it and feedback

Comment: I’ve updated my question. Still have no luck. :(

Comment: Do you have UninstallSchema in your module? http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html

Answer (score 1):

###### For a module installed with composer:

```bash
# uninstall the module
bin/magento module:uninstall Vendor_ModuleName

# reinstall the module, given that it is still defined in composer.json
composer install
```

###### For a custom (non-composer) module installed with [Setup/InstallData](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/migration-scripts/):

- Remove the module entry from the `setup_module` table
- Run the following command to install it again

```bash
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

###### For a custom (non-composer) module installed with [Data Patch](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/components/declarative-schema/patches/):

- Remove the module entry from the `patch_list` table, look for `patch_name like "%Vendor_ModuleName%"`

```bash
# uninstall the module
bin/magento module:uninstall --non-composer Vendor_ModuleName

# reinstall the module
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following commands serial wise to install the module

1 - php bin/magento setup:upgrade

2 - php bin/magento setup:di:compile

3 - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f