# Is it possible to delete the table from the database when uninstall the module?

Tags: magento2, database

Can I delete the table from the Magento database when the module is disabled and uninstalled?
Because the table was created when the module is installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `UninstallInterface` of your module to drop the tables during uninstall process:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Setup/Uninstall.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class Uninstall implements UninstallInterface
{
    /**
     * Module uninstall code
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function uninstall(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $connection = $setup->getConnection();
        $connection->dropTable($connection->getTableName('your_table_name_here'));
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

But this script works only when module has been installed using the **Composer**:

> Hence, it is recommended that for modules NOT installed via composer,
>   manual clean up of the database and filesystem is necessary. In module
>   enable/disable, the code is never removed from the filesystem, so that
>   it can be used if required at a later time. Hence, it is not removed
>   from the setup_module table.

([additional information here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109737/how-to-reinstall-magento-2-extension-properly)).