# Magento 2 - Table not deleting while uninstalling custom module using module:uninstall command

Tags: magento2, composer, uninstall-module

I'm a newbie in magento 2 development. I'm creating magento 2 module and testing with composer. My test project is in github. https://github.com/hussain-badusha/magento-badusha-test

In my module, i simply created a table in **Setup/InstallSchema**.
As everybody does, i just want to delete my table when the user is uninstalling my module. So, after minutes of surfing, i found a way and used **Setup/Uninstall** to delete the table.

But, the table is not deleting while i uninstall the module

To reproduce the error,
I installed it using composer by putting git url in repositories in magento installed root path. Then i used this command

```
composer require badusha/module-test @dev
```

To uninstall, i used this command

```
php bin/magento module:uninstall -r Badusha_Test
```

Uninstallation is successful but the table is not deleted.

Any help would be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share your setup install and uninstall code?

Comment: Yes sure. https://github.com/hussain-badusha/magento-badusha-test/blob/master/Setup/InstallSchema.php and https://github.com/hussain-badusha/magento-badusha-test/blob/master/Setup/Uninstall.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i'm grateful to you all who helped me in fixing this one.

By the way, i found the exact problem.

In uninstall script, the **getTableName** function does not return table name with prefix.
So the target table is not deleted because of incorrect table name.

To fix this issue, one need to replace the **dropTable** code

From

```
$connection->dropTable($connection->getTableName('your_table_name_here'));
```

To

```
$connection->dropTable($setup->getTable('your_table_name_here'));
```

Please note that you need to give **$setup** variable instead of $connection variable to get the table name with prefix.

That's it.

Once again,
Thanks to all

Comment: wow, has that been filed back to Magento? Because that is a silly oversight

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the `--remove-data` param?

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-uninstall-mods.html

Comment: Yes i did try that too. But same result

Answer (score 0):

If you need to automatically remove table, created by module, add option --remove-data.

```
magento module:uninstall [--backup-code] [--backup-media] [--backup-db] [-r|--remove-data] [-c|--clear-static-content] \ {ModuleName} ... {ModuleName}
```

Follow this link: https://firebearstudio.com/blog/how-to-uninstall-magento-2-modules-and-restore-magento-2-backups-rollbacks.html

**2nd Step**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UninstallInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class Uninstall implements UninstallInterface
{
    /**
     * Module uninstall code
     *
     * @param SchemaSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function uninstall(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $connection = $setup->getConnection();
        $connection->dropTable($connection->getTableName('your_table_name_here'));
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

**But this script works only when module has been installed using the Composer:**

Hence, it is recommended that for modules NOT installed via composer, manual clean up of the database and filesystem is necessary.

ref link : [Is it possible to delete the table from the database when uninstall the module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/124587/is-it-possible-to-delete-the-table-from-the-database-when-uninstall-the-module)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes i've already tried that method too using --remove-data parameter with module:uninstall command. But the custom table was not deleted while uninstallation was successful

Comment: code updated please check. Thank you

Comment: Thanks, i exactly did it in the way you are describing above. And yes i installed it via composer. Fyi, all filesystem, and setup_module row for my module, etc, are deleted automatically when i run module:uninstall command. The only problem i have is my custom table is not deleted.